# Read a CSV file stored on a web server using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $.get('m.csv', function(result) {
            $("div").html(result);
        });
    });
});​
```

When the button is clicked it replaces the text on web page with the text in a csv file. It works fine for files stored on my local machine however when I replace the `m.csv` with a csv file stored on web server (for example, http://www.abc.com/a.csv) it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to read documents issued from another domain, an operation which is now prevented by [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This can't work unless the server explicitly allows it by adding [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control).

If you can't ask the owners of the server to set the headers you need, your only solution would be to make those files appear as served by your server,

- either by downloading them
- or by using a proxy on your server.